# Why does this construct give no output control object?

Tags: gui-construction

```
Control@{h[3], 0, 1}
```

It is puzzling. (The motive for `h[i]` is to build a list of controls.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `Control` is just a wrapper for `` Manipulate`Control ``, and that function expects a Symbol as its first argument:

```
Control[]; (*preload*)

ClearAttributes[Manipulate`Control, {Protected, ReadProtected}]

Block[{$Context = "Manipulate`Dump`"},
 Definition[Manipulate`Control] // Print;
]
```

> ```
> Manipulate`Control[var_, Manipulate`Dump`opts___Rule, ControlType -> type_, 
>   opts2___Rule] := Manipulate`Control[var, type, Manipulate`Dump`opts, opts2]
>
> Manipulate`Control[var_Symbol, Manipulate`Dump`opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
>  Manipulate`Control[var, Automatic, Manipulate`Dump`opts]
>
> Manipulate`Control[{var_Symbol, args___}, Manipulate`Dump`opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
>   Manipulate`Control[{var, args}, Automatic, Manipulate`Dump`opts]
>
> . . .
> ```

All but the first definition use `_Symbol` which requires that the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of the expression be `Symbol`, and the first definition just calls one of the others.

This seems like an oversight as one can easily configure a slider with `h[3]`:

```
Dynamic[h[3]]
Slider[Dynamic[h[3]], {0, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard . The code you wrote is somewhat too complicated for me but I understand the comment following it. `Manipulate` too allows `h[3]`. But what is Manipulate`Control?

Comment: @User18 ``Manipulate`Control`` seems to be the internal function that `Control` is transformed into the course of evaluation and Front End formatting.  I am attempting to follow internal definitions to arrive at this conclusion.  The point is that if I am correct and `Control` relies upon ``Manipulate`Control``, and the latter only works with Symbols, then the observed behavior is expected if disappointing.

Comment: That's most helpful. It is strange that in the MMA Documentation I cannot find information about it, nor the usage of the ` sign acting _not_ as a number mark. Then where should I look them up?

Comment: @User18 ``Manipulate`Control`` is an internal, behind-the-scenes function and I would not expect to find documentation for it.  The use of the backtick here is for Context; this `Control` is in the context ``Manipulate` ``.  The regular `Control` is in the ``System` `` context.  See: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html

Comment: .@Mr.Wizard Having learned about contexts I now understand the code you posted. Thanks a lot! Ah, it seems we both had a little problem with typing code when the code contained the code wrapper.

Comment: @User18 Oops!  I usually look at the comments I post but I guess I forgot to this time.  Let me see if I can fix that with after-the-fact moderator-editing-powers. :^)